# Complete removal of anaconda in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a newbie in this WSL (even Linux command system in general) business.

I first installed my anaconda using the following tutorial :
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04/

but when they ask

> Installation finished. Do you wish the installer to prepend the
>   Anaconda3 install location to PATH in your /home/linuxize/.bashrc ?
>   [yes|no]

I accidentally pressed enter, which means "no". Causing me unable to follow the next step ahead. Then I wanted to restart all over again. Would you guys know what I should do?

Previously I had a doubt that my C drive would be enough, then I tried to install the .sh file again via the WSL command line into another directory another drive.

I naively deleted the whole folder of those installations (in another drive) via the windows file explorer, attempting to restart all over again. Now I am not sure whether it is really gone or remained in other places. While installation in C drive can't be deleted, it is %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs right?

I have tried rm -rf ~/anaconda3 command but as you can guess, it's done nothing.

Thank you

Comment: _Causing me unable to follow the next step ahead. _ I would be very surprised if it weren't possible to "fix"/do the same operation at a later time. _Previously I had a doubt that my C drive would be enough_ Enough what? That kind of came out of nowhere, how does it relate to the Anaconda issue? _Now I am not sure whether it is really gone or remained in other places._ If you search through your hard drive for "Anaconda" and "Conda" and delete any remaining files, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal window, and then remove your entire Anaconda directory, which has a name such as anaconda2 or anaconda3, by entering rm -rf ~/anaconda3.

Then you need to edit the .bashrc file with

nano .bashrc

Comment: what is nano .bashrc for? Is this a command to be typed in the terminal? What does it do?

Comment: nano it is the linux editor, if you can run it, you need to pip install, and the .bashrc is your enviroment variables for your linux session.